# Stack Smashing Detected - Aborted (core Dumped)

Tags: c

I cannot seem to find why this is stack smashing, the code is meant to read in some files, read each line and cat other lines on the end. but i get a stack smashing detected error at the very end of code.

Any ideas?

Code is :

```
void main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

char lineCount;
int count = 0;
size_t buffer_size = 40;
char *buffer =malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(char));
char *buffer2 =malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(char));
char *buffer3 =malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(char));
char *buffer4 =malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(char));
FILE *Dictionary, *Names;
Dictionary = fopen ("/home/overdog/Documents/Coding/dictionary.txt","r");
Names = fopen ("/home/overdog/Documents/Coding/rawnames.txt","r");
    while(-1 != getline(&buffer,&buffer_size,Dictionary))
    {
        count = count + 1;

        for (int i =1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            memcpy(buffer2,buffer,buffer_size);
            char num[1];
            RemoveEndLine(buffer2);
            sprintf(num,"%d",i);
            strcat(buffer2,num);
            printf("%s\n",buffer2);
                while(-1 != getline(&buffer3,&buffer_size,Names))
                {
                    memcpy(buffer4,buffer2,buffer_size);
                    printf("before break\n");
                    strcat(buffer4,buffer3);
                    printf("%s",buffer4);




                }


        }



    }
printf("Lines = %d \n",count);
free(buffer);
free(buffer2);
free(buffer3);
free(buffer4);
fclose(Dictionary);
fclose(Names);
printf("test\n");
}
```

The output seems OK, and the print of `"test"` at the end of the code prints. And then the Stack smashing error is seen.

Comment: since you are concatenating strings potentially 40-char long together into a 40-char long buffer, you're looking for trouble.

Comment: "If the buffer is not large enough to hold the line, getline() resizes it with realloc, updating *lineptr and *n as necessary."

Comment: @PaulOgilvie ok nice. The strcat part remains a problem, though, but the real issue is in the answer below.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, fully agree. Lots of problems here.

Comment: although 40 chars are OK to read one number per line...

Answer (score 4):

Lets take a close look at these two lines:

```
char num[1];
...
sprintf(num,"%d",i);
```

You declare `num` as an array of a *single* character, forgetting that (`char`) strings in C are really called ***null terminated*** *byte strings*. That means a string of a single character needs space for *two* `char` elements, to fit the terminator.

Since you don't have space for the terminator then `sprintf` will write *out of bounds* of your array, leading to *undefined behavior* and your smashed stack.

If you are certain that the number will never be more than a single digit (which it wont, it will include the two-digit number `10`), then you need to have an array of at least two character elements.

I also recommend you use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to avoid buffer overflows like that.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the help, what Some Programmer Dude said did help i think but i still had an issue. I found that the issue was the line

```
strcat(buffer4,buffer3);
```

As the buffer size for both was the same, it was creating a string which requires a buffer of 80?

i amended the line

```
char *buffer4 =malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(char));
```

to read

```
char *buffer4 =malloc(80 * sizeof(char));
```

And this now works without stack smashing

Thanks!